# error with rec.env['book.tickets'].search()

Tags: odoo

```
@api.depends('totalbook')
def _computebook(self):
    sum_a = 0
    for rec in self:
        for l in rec.env['book.tickets'].search([('status', 'in', ('sold', 'rent'))]):
            if l:
                sum_a += 1
        rec.currentbook = rec.totalbook - sum_a
```

I use this compute to calculate current book in library.
But when I run this code, the problem calculate of my each book base on all books.

Comment: `sum_a = 0` is declared outside the first loop and will be incremented for each line for all records (not for each record separately).

Answer (score 0):

When you are write any compute method in odoo, in self you will get all the list of browsable objects.

And then you are trying to search data from that  browsable object. That's why you get a error.

You have to use self.env instead of rec.env.

Because you can't search data from browsable object you can access only data of that browsable object.

You have to add limit 1 on when you are searching a record of multiple record are than you will get another expected Singleton error.

Either you can you use another loop after searching record.

Let me know if you face any errors again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this error occured because
whenever you are trying to make a object of another model at that time you should have to use with `self.env` instead of `rec.env` because in your method rec is just a record-set of your instance

so please update your method as per the following snippet.

```
for l in self.env['book.tickets'].search([('status', 'in', ('sold','rent'))]):
```